# How to provide different interfaces to an object (optimally)

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, multiple-instances

I need a way to provide different interfaces from a single object.
For example. User one should be able to call `Foo::bar()` and user 2 should be able to call `Foo::baz()` but user one cannot call `Foo::baz()` and respectively user two cannot call `Foo::bar()`.

I did manage to do this but I don't think that it's optimal.

```
class A
{
    public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};

class B
{
    public:
    virtual void baz() = 0;
    virtual ~B() = 0;
};

class Foo : public A, public B
{
    public:
    Foo() = default;
    void baz() override;
    void bar() override;

};

class Factory
{
    public:
    Factory()
    {
        foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<A> getUserOne()
    {
        return foo;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<B> getUserTwo()
    {
        return foo;
    }

    private:
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo;
};
```

Is there a better way to achieve this. Maybe with wrapper objects. I don't really need to allocate this foo object with `new`(`std::make_shared`) I even prefer not to, but I cannot use raw pointers and smart pointers give unnecessary overhead and system calls.

Edit: I'll try to give an example.
There is a car. User one is the driver. He can steer the wheel, accelerate or use the breaks. User two is the passenger and he can control the radio for example.
I don't want the passenger to be able to use the breaks or the driver to be able to use the radio.
Also they are both in the car so the actions of user one will have effect on user two and vice versa.

Comment: Who are user1 and user2? How do they get inside the same program in the first place? How do you decide that user1 is _really_ user1 and not user2, pretending?

Comment: Please read about the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your questions reads as " i did xy but i think it is not optimal, what else shoud I do?", but it is not 100% clear what is the actual problem you are trying to solve. What are the "users"? Why do you need different access?

Comment: Let me give an example. Imagine that the users are two different threads. One of them should be able to fill out some useful data in the class and the other should be able to read it, clear it maybe block the other user. In other words - one of the users should be able to use the object methods and the other should be able to control the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you essentially need is a shared data between two objects. The inheritance is not a very good choice for this because not only you do not need `is A` relationship but you explicitely want to avoid it. Therefore composition is your answer, especially since you have a factory:

```
class Data
{
public:
    void bar();
    void baz();
};
```

Then instead of inheritance you would use composition:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(Base *base) : mBase(base) {}

    void bar() { mBase->bar(); }

private:
    Base *mBase = nullptr;
};

//class B would be the same only doing baz()
```

Finally the `Factory`:

```
class Factory
{
public:
    A *getUserOne() { return &mA; }
    B *getUserTwo() { return &mB; }

private:
    Base mBase;
    A mA(&mBase);
    B mB(&mBase);
};
```

Couple of points about this solution. While it does not allocate on the heap you will need to keep the `Factory` alive as long as there are users of it. For this reason the use of `std::shared_ptr` as in the OP might be a *smart* idea. :-) But comes of course with the cost of the atomic reference counting.

Secondly `A` is not related to `B` in any way. This is by design and unlike the original solution does not allow `dynamic_cast` between `A` and `B`.

Lastly where the implementation will be is up to you. You can have it all in `Data` and have `A` and `B` merely call it (as in above) but you can also make `Data` into just a `struct` holding only your data and have the implementation of your methods in `A` and `B` respectively. The latter is more "data oriented" programming that has a lots of popularity these days as opposed to more traditional "object oriented" which is what I chose to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your data separately

```
struct Data
{
    /* member variables */
};
```

Have an interface class capable of manipulating said data will all members protected

```
class Interface
{
protected:
    Interface(Data &data) : m_data{data} {}

    void bar() { /* implementation */ }
    void baz() { /* implementation */ }

    Data &m_data;
};
```

Have derived classed that make public specific members

```
class A : private Interface
{
public:
    A(Data &data) : Interface{data} {}
    using Interface::bar;
};

class B : private Interface
{
public:
    B(Data &data) : Interface{data} {}
    using Interface::baz;
};
```

This way you can also have users capable of having overlapping access to some functionality without having to implement it multiple times.

```
class Admin : private Interface
{
public:
    Admin(Data &data) : Interface{data} {}
    using Interface::bar;
    using Interface::baz;
};
```

Of course, depending on how you're using the data, you might want a pointer or shared pointer, possibly add some syncronization between accesses from multiple threads.

Sample code using this model:

```
void test()
{
    Data d{};

    auto a = A{d};
    a.bar();
    // a.baz is protected so illegal to call here

    auto b = B{d};
    b.baz();
    // b.bar is protected so illegal to call here

    auto admin = Admin{d};
    admin.bar();
    admin.baz();
}
```

This seems to me efficient in the sense that you only have one set of data and a single implementation for data manipulation, no matter how many user types you have.